# Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, network

Visual Studio 2013、C#でAPIを開発しています。

APIの目的は携帯にメッセージを送ることで、最初はTimeOutエラーでしたが

```
req.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
```

上記の記述を追加したら `Unable to connect to the remote server` というエラーが出ました。
一体このエラーは何が原因で、どうすれば解決できますでしょうか？

```
public string SendSMS(string _message, string _phone_number)
{
    var enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("EUC-JP");
    var postData = "";

    try
    {
        //POST送信する文字列を作成
        postData = postData + String.Format("username={0}&", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_username));
        postData = postData + String.Format("password={0}&", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_password));
        postData = postData + String.Format("trigger_id={0}&", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_trigger_id1));
        postData = postData + String.Format("phone_number={0}&", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_PhoneNumber));
        postData = postData + String.Format("message={0}&", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_message));

        //バイト型配列に交換
        var postDataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        //WebRequestの作成
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_SMSURL);

        req.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;

        //メソッドにPOSTを指定
        req.Method = "POST";
        //ContentTypeを"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"にする
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //POST送信するデータの長さを指定
        req.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
        //データをPOST送信するためのStreamを取得
        System.IO.Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();

        //送信するデータを書き込む
        reqStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);

        reqStream.Close();

        //サーバーからの応答を受信するためのWebResponseを取得
        var res = req.GetResponse();
        //応答データを受信するためのStreamを取得
        var resStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        //XML形式へ
        var objXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(resStream);

        var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(objXMLReader);
        objXMLReader.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return " Send SMS Error " + e.Message + " log:" + _log;
    }
}
```

Comment: proxy 環境下などの理由で _SMSURL が指す URL に接続出来ないのではないでしょうか？もしくは相手から接続を拒否されている。(テストしすぎでBANされた、など)

Comment: 元々はVBで作られ、今使ってるのをC#で変換して使用しています。VBでのテストはできましたので相手サーバーに拒否されているのはないと思います。
コード以外にProxyなどの理由だと個人的には思っています。
でも、proxyってどんな役割をして、これを設定するにはどうすればいいんですか？

Comment: proxyはHTTP通信を中継するサーバーで、ネットワークによっては特定のproxyを通さないと外部にアクセスさせてくれないことがあるのです。が、そこに関してVBとC#での違いはないはずです。テストした環境が異なるとか、VB版をテストしたのはだいぶ前とか、そういうことはないですか？

Comment: @unarist  コメント、ありがとうございます。
VB版をテストしたのは一昨日で、他に少し気になるのはVBではHTTP通信ですが、C#ではHTTPSが基本になっていて、今日色々とproxyのコードを追加してテストしてみましたが、「the servicepointmanager does not support proxies with the https scheme」というエラーが出ました。
何かプロジェクトの環境の問題じゃないかとは思うんですが、どのへんなのかがよくわかりませんね..

Comment: `_SMSURL` の指すURLも変わっている（http/httpsの違いとか）のですか？

Comment: @unarist _SMSURL側でなく自分のサーバーURLと関連しているようです。
今まではウェブ発行してそのURLで試していました。先、デバッグモードでやってみたらちゃんとできました。今のプロジェクトではSSL有効化してウェブを発行しているので何らかの壁にぶつかっているのではないかと思われます。
今まで試していたURL：https://xxxxxx.net/api/SMS
デバッグ：http://localhost:xxxxx/api/SMS

Answer (score 1):

SSL/TLS のバージョンの問題であるかもしれません。

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

を追加して試してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

相手サーバーに拒否されているか、
自分の端末から出られていないかだと思います。

ファイアウォールの設定で、この通信が許可されているか(拒否されていないか)
確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。